# Mongoose aggregate returning empty result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have problems with a mongoose aggregate request.

It's kind of driving me crazy cause I can't find a solution anywhere. I would be very grateful for any support.

The schema:

```
var EvalSchema = new Schema({
    modified: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    created : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    item: {type: String, required: true},
    criteria: [{
        description: {
            type: String
        },
        eval: {
            type: Number
        }
    }]
});
mongoose.model('Eval', EvalSchema);
```

and I'm using an aggregation to compute the sum of evaluations for each criterion for a given item.

```
Eval.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        item: item.id
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$criteria"
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: "$criteria.description",
        total: {
            $sum: "$criteria.eval"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        total: 1,
        count: 1,
        value: {
            $divide: ["$total", "$count"]
        }
    }
}], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result);
});
```

Result is always empty....

I'm logging all queries that mongoose fire in the application. When I run the query in Mongodb, it returns the correct result.

```
coll.aggregate([{
    '$match': {
        item: 'kkkkkkkkkkk'
    }
}, {
    '$unwind': '$criteria'
}, {
    '$group': {
        _id: '$criteria.description',
        total: {
            '$sum': '$criteria.eval'
        },
        count: {
            '$sum': 1
        }
    }
}, {
    '$project': {
        total: 1,
        count: 1,
        value: {
            '$divide': ['$total', '$count']
        }
    }
}])
```

Result:

```
{
    result: [{
        "_id": "Overall satisfaction",
        "total": 4,
        "count": 1,
        "value": 4
    }, {
        "_id": "service",
        "total": 3,
        "count": 1,
        "value": 3
    }, {
        "_id": "Quality",
        "total": 2,
        "count": 1,
        "value": 2
    }, {
        "_id": "Price",
        "total": 1,
        "count": 1,
        "value": 1
    }],
    ok: 1
}
```

The model is referencing the correct collection.

Thank you :)

Comment: Have you checked the value coming from `item.id`?

Comment: Yes I did. It contains the correct value. :(

Comment: Check the type of the item.id. Maybe it is not a string.

Comment: The type of item.id is a string... :(

Comment: Try the aggregation pipeline without the `$match` operator stage, and see if that returns anything. If it does then there is something wrong with your `item.id` value.

Comment: Yes, thank you!!!!!!!!!! it returns something. There seems to be something wrong with item.id.

Comment: What a bad day!!!!!! Issue fixed!!! I was trying to compute the sum before saving the item in evals. :/

Comment: For any lost soul who ends up here, in my case the problem was that I had been passing the ids as *Strings* in the `match`. When we passed the ids as *ObjectID*s instead, the aggregation worked. It turns out *ObjectID*s are needed for aggregate even though they are not needed for find.

Comment: @joeytwiddle wow that is hard to track down. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi lol I'm back again. This time to say the same problem exists with *Date*s. Your `find()` query might work fine comparing a *Number* against a *Date* in the DB. But for `aggregate()` your `match` had better compare a `new Date()` against a *Date* in the DB.

Comment: Wow! For me, the solution was to change `_id` by `id`. Does someone have an explication for that? (solve a problem by making a typo is priceless)

Answer (score 15):

Your `item.id` in the `$match` function is a String, therefore you will need to convert it to an **ObjectID**, like so:

`$match: { item: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(item.id) }`

You can refer to this issue on GitHub [aggregate](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1399) for more details.

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks!

Comment: @Chris great! Glad that did it for you

Comment: Life saver man. Glad I found your solution.